# Download files with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, download

I need to allow the user to download an array of bytes I get from a REST api.

The backend api return something like this:

```
GET /api/files/123
{
  filename: 'myfile.pdf',
  file: [base64]
}
```

On my html I have something like this:

```
<div ng-click="click()">Download</div>
```

And somewhere in my controller I have:

```
$scope.click: function (){
   $http.get('/api/files/123',{headers:{x-security:'some_sec_token'}})
   .then(
     function (response){
       // do something to return the array of bytes
     },
     function (error){
       console.log(error);
     }
   );
}
```

I'm stuck on how to return the array of bytes with the Content-Disposition header using the filename returned by the api.

Comment: Do you want to only download the array of bytes ? or allow the user to create a file with the array of bytes as content ?

Comment: to download a file with the name "myfile.pdf" and with the array of bytes as the content of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a file using the array of bytes as content then you can use this library:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js

Import that library in you angular project and then try this:

```
var blob = new Blob(<arrayOfBytes>, {type: <yourFileType>});
saveAs(blob, [nameToSave]);
```

**yourFileType** should be something like "image/jpg" or similar depending on your file type

**nameTosave** should have the file type as well.. example: "myFile.pdf"

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, but the library failed on line 129 with this error: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: What are u passing as parameter to the blob ?. What browser are you using?. Can you check in console or maybe debugging if the blob creation is ok ?

Comment: That's it, the blob was not being created correctly. Now it is solved. Thanks!